# What's the closest OSS license on CodePlex to the CodeProject license?

Tags: codeplex

There's some code on CodeProject that's already OSS under the [CodeProject license](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx).

I've contacted the author several times on his blog, but he's not responding to any request for putting the code on CodePlex (or any email at all).

Since it's OSS anyway, I thought I'd do it without his permission (and ofcourse give him all the credit).

I figure this is ethically okay as long as I choose the closest license to the codeproject license.

Does anyone know the closest license to the [CodeProject one](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx) I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CodePlex you can use a custom license. Just copy over the CodeProject license.

Comment: On that CodeProject link: "The CPOL is our gift to the community. We encourage everyone to use this license if they wish regardless of whether the code is posted on CodeProject.com."

Answer (score 2):

You cant change the license on a piece of code without the authors permission. End of story, full stop, etc etc.

If you are embedding it in another project (as I believe the CodeProject license allows), then make sure to put a notice inside your COPYING file (or equivilent) with a copy of the codeproject license, the affected file[s] and the authors legal name.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a question for a lawyer. Comparing licenses for some kind of "equivalence" is very hard.